# how to run .feature + _spec.rb + _test.rb with autotest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cucumber, autotest, zentest

In one of my project with some existing code, some code is covered by _test.rb file, other is by _spec.rb and we introduced .feature

It became a nice mixture of stuff to check.
I am stumped how to run .feature, _spec.rb and _test.rb for red-green cycles.

Answer (score 0):

After some searching around the web, I found the solution in .autotest file

```
Autotest.add_hook :reset do |at|
  # at.clear_mappings
  at.add_mapping(/^(.*?)(_spec)?\.rb$/) { |filename, m| m[2] ? filename : "#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
end
```

obviously with all appropriate gems installed, simply run autotest

I am now looking for a smarter /better/ optimized way to do this.